# Изменение цвета текста и иконки TabLayout

Tags: android, kotlin

Как у `Tablayout` отключить изменение цвета текста при пролистывании, т.е. чтобы цвет не менялся, когда `scrollBar` находится по середине. Или как можно сделать, чтобы цвета иконки и текста менялись синхронно, так как сначала меняется цвет текста , а потом уже иконки. Если кликать по `tab`-ам, а не листать, то цвета меняются синхронно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Xml:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/player_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:elevation="20dp"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/player_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                    app:tabMode="fixed"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
                    app:tabTextColor="?attr/tabTextColor"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="?attr/seekBarColor"
                    app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="?attr/primaryTextColor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Activity:**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    setTheme(Constants.themeId)

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(player_toolbar)

    val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer_layout, player_toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close
    )

    drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()

    nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

    player_pager.offscreenPageLimit = 4
    setupPager(player_pager)
    tab_layout.setupWithViewPager(player_pager)



    tab_layout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
        override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
        }

        override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
            when (tab?.position) {
                0 -> {tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_list_default)}
                1 -> {tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_albums_default)}
                2 -> {tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_playlist_default)}
                3 -> {tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_radio_default)}
            }

        }

        override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
            when (tab?.position) {
                0 -> {tab.setIcon(getStyleableDrawable(R.attr.allTracksIcon))}
                1 -> {tab.setIcon(getStyleableDrawable(R.attr.albumsIcon))}
                2 -> {tab.setIcon(getStyleableDrawable(R.attr.playlistIcon))}
                3 -> {tab.setIcon(getStyleableDrawable(R.attr.radioIcon))}
            }
        }

    })

    setupTabIcons()
    player_pager.currentItem = 0

    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.playback_container, FullScreenPlaybackFragment(), "PlaybackFragment")
        .commit()
}
```

Comment: а если в функции `onTabUnselected` устанавливать еще и цвет текста, или вы так уже пробовали?

Comment: Цвет становится исходным,  когда происходит переход на другой таб.  Мне кажется для изменения цвета текста используется другой слушатель,  по умолчанию.  Все перерыл,  но так и не могу понять как сделать.  Можно для таба установить кастомный layout и уже, зная Id, в методе onTabSelected изменять цвет текста.  Но по мне так это не совсем хорошее решение.